# hiding field in a form when a value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the following function working but it doesn't and I can't figure out why

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideLevel() {
        if if isNaN($('#id_course')) {
            $('#id_level').hide();
            $('#level').hide();
            $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').hide();
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(hideLevel);
    $('#id_course').change(hideLevel);
</script>
```

I'm just trying to hide form fields when a value is selected. I mean, when somebody select a value which will be a number, some fields whill have to disappear.

Here is the html code of the form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Cours</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="id_course" name="course">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                    <option value="nl">Néerlandais</option>
                    <option value="fr">Français</option>
                    <option value="01">Anglais</option>
                    <option value="02">Allemand</option>
                    <option value="03">Latin</option>
                </select><br>

            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Niveau</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <ul id="id_level">
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_level_0"><input class="level" id="id_level_0" name="level" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1ère secondaire</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_level_1"><input class="level" id="id_level_1" name="level" type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2ème secondaire</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_level_10"><input class="level" id="id_level_3" name="level" type="checkbox" value="4" /> 4ème secondaire</label>
                    </li></ul><br>

            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-actions">
    <br><br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Publier" /><br><br><br> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm learning Jquery but in this simple script, I just can't see where is the problem  :(

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dvryqvLz/1/

```
----
EDIT
----
```

I realize now that the problem is the isNaN function and I didn't explain why I want to use it, please excuse me for that.

I have two sort of course and based on the course, I want to make some field disappear. My idea was to make a distinction between number and string. One category will have values as string and the other as number. The function must just distinct whether the value is a number or not and if it is, fields must disappear.

Anyway, thank you for your answers :)

Comment: You have `if if ` that should be single `if`.

Comment: Why are you checking if a jQuery object `isNaN`? that will always be true. Did you want to run the objects `val()` through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss parentheses `()` in `if` condition :

```
if !isNaN($('#id_course')) {
```

Should be :

```
if ( !isNaN($('#id_course')) ) {
```

And also you have to use `.val()` to get the value of selected element in condition :

```
if ( !isNaN( $('#id_course').val() ) ) {
```

You can use :

```
$(function(){ //Ready function
     hideLevel();
     $('body').on('change', '#id_course', function(){
        hideLevel();
     });
});
```

Instead of :

```
$(document).ready(hideLevel);
$('#id_course').change(hideLevel);
```

**NOTE :** in example bellow you can see the else clause added because when you select another element with number value you have to show the fields again.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function hideLevel() {
    if ( isNaN($('#id_course').val()) || $('#id_course').val() == "") {
        $('#id_level').show();
        $('#level').show();
        $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').show();
    }else{
        $('#id_level').hide();
        $('#level').hide();
        $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').hide();
    }
}

$(function(){ //Ready function
    hideLevel();

    $('#id_course').on('change', function(){
        hideLevel();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Cours</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="id_course" name="course">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                    <option value="nl">Néerlandais</option>
                    <option value="fr">Français</option>
                    <option value="01">Anglais</option>
                    <option value="02">Allemand</option>
                    <option value="03">Latin</option>
                </select><br>
                            
            </div>
    </div>

       
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Niveau</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <ul id="id_level">
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_level_0"><input class="level" id="id_level_0" name="level" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1ère secondaire</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_level_1"><input class="level" id="id_level_1" name="level" type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2ème secondaire</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_level_10"><input class="level" id="id_level_3" name="level" type="checkbox" value="4" /> 4ème secondaire</label>
                    </li></ul><br>
                            
            </div>
    </div>
                

    <div class="form-actions">
    <br><br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Publier" /><br><br><br> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `onchange` code was fine, your way is more neat but not more correct. For the rest your totally right :)

Comment: Thank you very much :D

But now, what strategy should I follow if I don't want the field to disappear if no course is selected?

Comment: You're welcome, in my opinion better if you change your condition to `if ( isNaN($('#id_course').val()) || $('#id_course').val() == "") {` see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`isNan` is a function which is used to check if the following value can be converted into a number or not. It would not be application on an element. You should use `.length` property to check if the element exists.

```
if($('#id_course').length > 0) 
{
   $('#id_level').hide();
   $('#level').hide();
   $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').hide();
}
```

To check the value for `NaN`:

```
  if(!isNaN($('#id_course').val()))
  {
     $('#id_level').hide();
     $('#level').hide();
     $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').hide();
  }
```

Comment: `(!isNaN($('#id_course').val())` you miss a parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You check `isNaN($("#id_course"))` while you probably want to check if the value of `$("#id_course")` is not "" (the empty string). `!isNaN` is in this case not the correct function to use because it will return true even for the empty string.

```
function hideLevel() {
    if ($('#id_course').val()!="") {
        $('#id_level').hide();
        $('#level').hide();
        $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').hide();
    }
}
hideLevel();
$('#id_course').change(hideLevel);
```

You can view a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvryqvLz/5/

---

**EDIT**
I first thought you want to hide the group when there is an option selected, now I realize that you probably want to hide the group when there is **not** an option selected. In that case you **can** use `isNaN`:

```
function hideLevel() {
   if (!isNaN($('#id_course').val())) {
        $('#id_level').hide();
        $('#level').hide();
        $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').hide();
    }else{
        $('#id_level').show();
        $('#level').show();
        $('#id_level').parents('.control-group').show();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvryqvLz/6/